# mv/rename files with common part but unknown file pattern

Tags: linux, rename, mv

I would like to rename the beginning of different files.

input:

```
myfilename abc yeswithspaces.abc
myfilename def yeswithspaces.abc
myfilename_abc_nospaces.abc
myfilename def blabla.def
myfilename_abc_mainfile.ok
```

output wanted:

```
newfilename abc yeswithspaces.abc
newfilename def yeswithspaces.abc
newfilename_abc_nospaces.abc
myfilename def blabla.def
myfilename_abc_mainfile.ok
```

I have this code which works ok, if I have only one file .abc but not if there is more:

```
if [ -e "${DOSSIER}/${OLD_NAME}"*.abc ];
    then
        for i in "${DOSSIER}/$OLD_NAME"*.abc; do
        [ -f "$i" ] || continue
        mv "$i" "${i/$OLD_NAME/$NEW_NAME}"
    done
fi
```

Comment: try rename command, for ex: rename 'my' mine *.abc

Comment: rename is not installed and since it's for an app to be deployed, I can't add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't looking at the right place for my problem
the if was my reel problem. this is ok!

```
ABC_Files=$(ls "$DOSSIER/$OLD_NAME"*.abc 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
    if [ **"$ABC_Files" != "0"** ];
        then
            for i in "${DOSSIER}/$OLD_NAME"*.abc; do
                [ -f "$i" ] || continue
                mv "$i" "${i/$OLD_NAME/$NEW_NAME}"
            done
    fi
```

of course assuming you know that

$DOSSIER is the path

$OLD_NAME is your actual filename

$NEW_NAME is your new filename

Answer (score 0):

For example, if `mynamefile` has length 10 you can write

```
len = ${#OLD_NAME}
for filename in $(ls | grep .abc) 
do
    suffix = $(filename:$len)
    mv filename $newname$suffix
done
```

Comment: I can't, filename has no defined lenght and can contain spaces... it would be too easy :D

Comment: filename does not need to have definite length, only myfilename needs to. If I didn't misunderstood myfilename is the common part of the filenames.

Comment: yes sorry that is what I what trying to say. myfilename has no defined lenght

Comment: okay, I think you should edit your question writing a different myfilename for every file, because it can be easily misunderstood. By the way, if there is no pattern in the names I don't see any possible solution. Do you know the oldname a priori?

Comment: I'll try to edit title. files have no patterns but I do have the "myfilename" part in var $OLD_NAME